# Python - read with key in App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a python program in Google App Engine

When finding an object in the datastore when I have the key as a string, how can I do a direct read. Below is my code which is performing a loop, not good.....

```
class Opportunity(db.Model):
    customer = db.ReferenceProperty(Customer,collection_name='opportunitys')
    BNusername = db.StringProperty()
    opportunity_no = db.StringProperty()
    # etc etc etc.....

#BnPresets holds the object key as a string 

opportunitys = Opportunity.all()
opportunitys.filter('BNusername =',BnPresets.myusername)
for oprec in opportunitys:
    if str(oprec.key()) == BnPresets.recordkey:
         opportunity = oprec
         # I have the object here and can process etc etc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can instantiate `db.Key` from string by passing it directly to the constructor:

```
opportunity_key = db.Key(BnPresets.recordkey)
```

Once you have that, simply `db.get` to obtain the entity identified by this key:

```
opportunity = db.get(opportunity_key)
```

I guess (by looking at the query you use) that you also want to verify the username of the object you got:

```
if opportunity.BNusername == BnPresets.myusername
    process_opportunity(opportunity)
```

That should be pretty much it. The bottom line is that you should use the key first - as it uniquely identifies your entity - rather than querying for some other property and iterating through results.

Comment: I am guessing that the opportunity = db.get(opportunity_key)  goes in the class Opportunity(db.Model):  section. Which would mean I always use the same variable to hold the KEY when I do the db.get.  I also assume that the opportunitys = Opportunity.all() etc code will work when I want to get several objects.  Do I have this right?

Comment: Note that db.get will also work directly on the string representation of a key. You can skip the first step and just do opportunity = db.get(BnPresets.recordkey).